# How do I make a userform appear on demand in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can make it popup on opening the document, but what if I close the userform and want to it to show up again in the same document? I know in excel you can add a button onto a worksheet directly and make it show the userform on click, but this button is unavailable for microsoft Word. Is there a solution besides initiating the script by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a VBA userform, you can trigger it from a [macrobutton](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/UsingMacroButton.htm) field, from a [form field](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/master_your_formfields.html), from a [shape](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/24501-assign-macro-shape-word-2013-a.html), from a [QAT button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c) or from an [ActiveX button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283). There are probably a couple of other methods I'm not remembering at the moment. Each is a little different in the exact steps, but all will run the command:

```
UserFormName.Show
```